# Error al abrir dialog desde un menú

Tags: android, kotlin, alertdialog

Tengo una activity con un menú desde el que se despliega un dialog personalizado que he creado en la carpeta layout.

El error me sale al querer desplegar el dialog desde el método `onOptionsItemSelected` que lo estoy llamando desde el activity *ReproductorVideosActivity*

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
```

```
    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu : Menu): Boolean{
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_visitas, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item : MenuItem): Boolean {
        val dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this@ReproductorVideosActivity)
        val dialogView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_visitas, null)

        val tvTitulo = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.dialog_tvTitulo)
        val tvVisitas = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.dialog_tvVisitas)
        val etVisitasMin = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.dialog_etVisitasMin)
        val etVisitasMax = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.dialog_etVisitasMax)
        val btnGuardar = findViewById<Button>(R.id.dialog_btnGuardar)
        val btnCancelar = findViewById<Button>(R.id.dialog_btnCancelar)

        dialog.setView(dialogView)
        val dialog1 = dialog.create()
        dialog1.show()

        //Botón cancelar de dialog
        btnCancelar.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener() {
            fun onClick(v: View) {
                dialog1.dismiss()
            }
        })
        return true
    }
```

He visto posibles soluciones, pero el problema es que el dialog lo tengo creado desde antes, no lo creo en el momento desde el *AlertDialog.Builder*

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12600877/setonclicklistener-error-in-custom-dialog

Y he intentado de esa forma, que hace que el aparezca el dialog sin error, pero los botones no hacen nada

**EDIT:**

Con lo que me han respondido ya no falla, al darle al botón en el menú lanza el dialog pero al pulsar el botón no hace nada. El código ahora mismo está así

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu : Menu): Boolean{
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_visitas, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item : MenuItem): Boolean {
        val dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this@ReproductorVideosActivity)
        val dialogView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_visitas, null)

        val tvTitulo = dialogView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.dialog_tvTitulo)
        val tvVisitas = dialogView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.dialog_tvVisitas)
        val etVisitasMin = dialogView.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.dialog_etVisitasMin)
        val etVisitasMax = dialogView.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.dialog_etVisitasMax)
        val btnGuardar = dialogView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.dialog_btnGuardar)
        val btnCancelar = dialogView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.dialog_btnCancelar)

        dialog.setView(dialogView)
        val dialog1 = dialog.create()
        dialog1.show()

        //Botón cancelar de dialog
        btnCancelar.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener() {
            fun onClick(v: View) {
                dialog1.dismiss()
            }
        })
        return true
    }
```

Comment: "No hace nada" , te refieres a que no cierra el dialogo? es que eso es lo que hace al dar click en btnCancelar.

Comment: Tengo otro botón con un código más grande, pero ninguno de los dos hace nada, pero en el caso que expongo el botón no cierra el diálogo. Como si el método del click no lo cogiera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findViewById` busca en layout de la activty por lo tanto nunca va a encontrar la view con el id `R.id.dialog_btnCancelar` porque no está en la activity sino en el dialog. Todo lo que debes hacer para encontrarlo es buscarlo dentro de la view del dialog

```
val btnCancelar = dialogView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.dialog_btnCancelar)
```

**EDIT**
Solución al segundo problema

La sintaxis que usaste para definir el clickListener es de Java. En Kotlin no necesitas declarar el método porque todo lo que está dentro de las llaves `{}` ya es la implementación de ese método. Es decir que simplemente debías escribir esto

```
btnCancelar.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener() {
    dialog1.dismiss()
})
```

Lo que hacía tu código original era crear un función local pero nunca la ejecutaba. Para que funcione de esa manera tendrías que haber llamado a esa función después de declararla

```
btnCancelar.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener() {
    fun onClick(v: View) {
        dialog1.dismiss()
    }
    // faltaba esta línea
    onClick(it)
})
```

Aunque por su puesto esto genera un overhead innecesario.

En estos casos lo ideal es usar la sintaxis [trailing lambda](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#passing-trailing-lambdas)

```
btnCancelar.setOnClickListener { dialog1.dismiss() }
```

Comment: Ya no falla al abrir el dialog, pero el botón de dentro del dialog no me funciona **btnCancelar**

Comment: actualiza tu pregunta mostrando un [mre] para reproducir el problema

Comment: Acabo de editar la pregunta con lo que me has dicho :)

Comment: Bien, pude reproducirlo. No sé porque pero parece que sólo sucede cuando seteas el clickListener de la manera antigua. Prueba reemplazarlo por `btnCancelar.setOnClickListener { dialog1.dismiss() }` y avisame si se soluciona

Comment: Siii!!! Funciona, no tiene mucho sentido porque al final hacen lo mismo, pero lo importante es que funcione, muchas gracias!!!!!

Comment: Lo siento, el error era muy obvio sólo que los que trabajamos con varios lenguajes aveces olvidamos qué cosa pertenece a cada uno